# ibm connections API error Invalid ServerBean implementation connections

Tags: xpages, ibm-sbt

I am currently developing an xpage web portal, the goal of this application is to intergrate the ibm connections 4.5 into my xpage app.

i have folowing the tutorial about it en trying the sbt toolkit tutorial voor de xpage, but i stil get this error:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=11, col=17: Error while executing function '@Endpoint'
Invalid ServerBean implementation connections.

this is my managed bean:

---

**

```
> <managed-bean>
>     <managed-bean-name>connections</managed-bean-name>
>     <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.ConnectionsBasicEndpoint
>       </managed-bean-class>
>     <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
>     <managed-property>
>       <property-name>url</property-name>
>       <value>http://linkedx.ilionx.com</value>
>     </managed-property>
>     <managed-property>
>       <property-name>authenticationService</property-name>
>       <value>/communities/service/atom/communities/all</value>
>     </managed-property>
>     <!--     Trust the connection -->
>     <managed-property>
>       <property-name>forceTrustSSLCertificate</property-name>
>       <value>true</value>
>     </managed-property>
>     <managed-property>
>       <property-name>authenticationPage</property-name>
>       <value>/SBT/Portal/WebPortal.nsf/_BasicLogin.xsp?endpoint=connections</value>
>     </managed-property>   </managed-bean>**
```

i am using ibm notes 9, and alreay installed the needed libraires.

can somone help me with this error?

i am using ibm notes 9, and alreay installed the needed libraires.

can somone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing ?

```
<managed-property>
    <property-name>authenticationPage</property-name>
    <value>/SBT/Portal/WebPortal.nsf/_BasicLogin.xsp?endpoint=connections</value>
</managed-property>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul Bastide for uw answer.

Comment: i have removed the managed bean-property authenticationPage but i stil get the same error.

Comment: do you see ">     " in your managed-beans.xml ? if so remove them * they are at the beginning of each of the lines above.

Comment: the application works perefect on my localhost but not on our work server

Comment: thanx Paul, it was a probleem with the libraries, i've reinstalled the libs and it works.